# Problem in using thickbox3.1 with rails..!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thickbox

I am using rails to build my application and I want a thickbox on clicking a particular link..
I use the below code in my partial which is displayed in a division of a page and on clicking the user.name, i need the thickbox.. when i use the below code, nothing happens..
`<%= link_to_function user.name,remote_function(:update=>"result", :url => {:action => :resultsuser}, :with => "'id='+#{user.id}+'&height=400&width=600'") %>`
i have included the 
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'thickbox' %>

jQuery.noConflict()

<%= stylesheet_link_tag("thickbox") %>`

and also replaced all $ by jQuery in the thickbox.js file.. nothing happens..
please help me out.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Firebug console when you click on the user name?

Comment: no.. nothing happens.. the values of height and width are present in the post variable and the result shows up in Console Response...

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

into a scripttag?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class option in the `link_to_function` helper method.

`<%= link_to_function user.name,remote_function(:update=>"result", :url => {:action => :resultsuser}, :with => "'id='+#{user.id}+'&height=400&width=600'", :class => "thickbox") %>`